# How do I find the path of my libpng/16 (Bash)?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having trouble installing R packages when using a HPC in interactive mode.

Via Bash, I need to load modules etc before launching R.

I get the error of /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng16. I have been advised to add this to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, using the path opt/gridware../apps/libpng/16; however, I want to be able to find the ... and need the full path. How would I find this please?

When using echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and printenv, I know my lib path does not contain anything to do with libpng/16.

Comment: How do you know you _have_ a `libpng16` to find? Something you never installed, well, _just isn't there_. (BTW, it's just `libpng16`, not `libpng/16`; the `/` might be there in a directory that this "gridware" company's software creates, but if their software isn't installed, then, well, it isn't installed)

Comment: In general, this is something to bring to your system administration team more than a problem Stack Overflow can help with.

Comment: Try   . . . . find / -name '*libpng*16' -print  . . . . then scan the results for appropriate references.  If none stand out, as Charles said, it is likely not installed.